# How do I install tar bz2 and gz files? 

Tags: installation, install-from-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a .tar.gz file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-file)

I Don't know how to install .tar, .bz2 and .gz packages.
For example how do I install [this](http://www.k3b.org)?