# ./configure not working

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, java, compiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install tar bz2 and gz files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80592/how-do-i-install-tar-bz2-and-gz-files)

I am trying to install Java 7 via tar.gz, but when it comes to the command "./configure", it says it don't exist. I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with latest updates.

The manual I looked is this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-tarballs/

Comment: did you do the part of `cd path-to-software` ?

Comment: What tar.gz file is it? Each tarball is different, and you need to view the README or INSTALL file to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have an already compiled TAR ball from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html therefore you don't need to compile JAVA.

In a nutshell: Simply extract it into a folder (sometimes /opt/java) and create a symlink of the java executable to /usr/bin/java and configure further with `update-alternatives`.

See the [Easy Linux Tips Project](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/): [Oracle (Sun) Java JRE for Ubuntu, Linux Mint and Debian](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java) for detailed instructions.