# How do I install a .TGZ file in Ubuntu 10.11?

Tags: software-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install tar bz2 and gz files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80592/how-do-i-install-tar-bz2-and-gz-files)

I'm trying to install "Sunflower" file browser app in Ubuntu. I downloaded the installer and it's a .TGZ file. How do I install it?

Can somebody walk me through the steps from de-compressing to what must be keyed in to the terminal and where must I place the installation folder.

The file is saved on home folder, under a folder called "Downloads". I renamed the compressed file to just "Sunflower.tgz" and moved it on the Home Folder.

I typed "tar xfvz sunflower.tgz on terminal but can't find the file. Is it because I renamed it?

Comment: `.tgz` is just a shortening of `.tar.gz`. You can extract it by right clicking it. And you should note that everything in Linux is case sensitive. If you rename something to `ABC` and then try to access it from `abc` it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

1 thing: linux is case sensitive. You used `tar xfvz sunflower.tgz` and state the name of the file is `Sunflower.tgz`. That might be the problem you face with the extracting not working.

I would advice using a PPA or a DEB if possible.

The [google code sunflower](http://code.google.com/p/sunflower-fm/) website points to a [Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/sunflower) with a PPA. This one seems outdated but the 1st link also has a deb install file: [sunflower 0.1a.42-1](http://code.google.com/p/sunflower-fm/downloads/detail?name=sunflower-0.1a.42-1.all.deb). You can open the last one with Ubuntu Software Center and have it check the package.

Seems easier to me ;)